# Как передать массив в поток?

Tags: java, массивы, многопоточность

Подскажите как передать заполнений рандомными числами массив arr в поток, для подсчета суммы...

```
public class ff {
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

    new Threard1().list();

    long timer = -System.currentTimeMillis();

    Runnable r1 = new Threard1();
    Thread t1 = new Thread(r1);

    t1.start();

    t1.join();

    System.out.print("\n\n" + "mainSum: " + new Threard1().getSum());

    timer += System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println("\n" + "Time: " + timer + "\n");
    }
```

}

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Threard1 implements Runnable{
private String title = "One";
private int delay=0;
private int sizeArr=5;
int sum;
public int arr[] = new int[sizeArr];

public void list () {

    Random rand = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeArr; i++) {
        arr[i] = rand.nextInt(10);
        System.out.print("\n" + title + ": " + arr[i]);
    }
}


public void run() {
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeArr; i++) {
        sum = sum + arr[i];
    }
        try {
            Thread.sleep(delay);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}

public int getSum () {
    return sum;
}
```

}

Comment: инстанция созданная в new Threard1().list() теряется.  Runnable r1 = new Threard1(); создаёт новую инстанцию. Очевидно, это должна быть одна и та же

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для начала нужно определиться в каком классе нам нужен массив.

Если нам зачем-то в дальнейшем этот массив понадобится в классе ff, то создавать массив нужно именно в нём. А затем думать над передачей этого массива. Я бы передал его с помощью конструктора.

Если нужно создавать массив в Threard1, то я бы создавал его не отдельным методом, а, допустим, вызывал бы его создание из метода run.

И в любом случае не нужно терять ссылки на объект, потому что:

```
new Threard1().list();

Runnable r1 = new Threard1();
Thread t1 = new Thread(r1);

System.out.print("\n\n" + "mainSum: " + new Threard1().getSum());
```

Это 3 разных экземпляра с тремя разными массивами.

В main я бы написал вот так:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException
{
    long timer = -System.currentTimeMillis();

    Threard1 threard1 = new Threard1();
    Thread thread = new Thread(threard1);
    thread.start();
    thread.join();

    timer += System.currentTimeMillis();

    System.out.println("==================");
    System.out.println("mainSum: " + threard1.getSum());
    System.out.println("Time: " + timer);
}
```

А в run() добавил бы:

```
this.list();
```